# $ \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-2x^{2}} $

Tags: limits

I want to determine
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-2x^{2}}
$$

Hint: use that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x} =1
$$

I managed to show the hint; I took $h = \ln(1+x)$ and used that $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{h} -1}{h} =1$.

But I don't know how to use this tip. I tried to make a change of variable, but I couldn't.

Comment: *Hint:* $$\dfrac{\ln\!\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-2x^{2}}=\frac1{2(1+x)^2}\cdot\dfrac{\ln\!\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-\dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^2}}.$$

Comment: @nejimban thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-2x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1 + \dfrac{-x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{\frac{-x^{2}}{(1+x)^2}(1+x)^2}$$
And then use the properties of limits.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}\bigg)}{-2x^{2}} = & \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1 - \dfrac{x^2}{(1+x)^{2}}\right)}{-\dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}} \cdot \frac{-\dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}}{-2x^2} \\= & \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1 - \dfrac{x^2}{(1+x)^{2}}\right)}{-\dfrac{x^{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: The sign so $\dfrac{1}{2}$ goes to the other term to be able to use stay. So the answer is $\dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: thank you very much